# Young's inequality

Tags: inequality, convolution, lp-spaces

Let $U \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\rho \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $\rho \ge 0$ and the support of $\rho$ is included in $B(0,1)$ (the euclidean unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^d$). Is there a way to bound the integral, where $K$ is a compact of $\mathbb{R}^d$,
$$\int_K \int_{B(0,1)} U(x-y) \rho(y) \text{d}y \text{d}x $$
by the $L^1$-norm of $U$ on a compact (may be on $K+B(0,1)$) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $K-B(0,1)$ it does work. Indeed,

\begin{eqnarray} \int_{K}|U(x-y)||\rho(y)|dx &=& |\rho(y)|\int_{K}|U(x-y)|dx     \\
   &=& |\rho(y)|\int_{K-\{y\}}|U(z)|dx \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

where $K-\{y\}=\{x-y,\ x\in K\}$. We get from $(1)$ that $$\int_K |U(x-y)||\rho(y)|dx\leq |\rho(y)|\|U\|_{L^1(K-B(0,1))}\tag{2}$$

We conclude from $(2)$ that $$\int_{B(0,1)}\int_K|U(x-y)||\rho(y)|dx dy=\|\rho\|_{L^1(B(0,1))}\|U\|_{L^1(K-B(0,1))}\tag{3}$$

To finalize, apply Fubini's Theorem.

Remark: I just realized that $K- B(0,1)=K+B(0,1)$.

Comment: I have some problems to get $(2)$ from $(1)$, could you explain a little more ?

Comment: Sure @user37238. Note that $K-\{y\}\subset K- B(0,1)$, hence, $\int_{K-\{y\}} |U(z)|\leq \int_{K-B(0,1)}|U(z)|$

Comment: Of course...now I see it! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome @user37238